# nginx - nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

All of a sudden I am getting the below nginx error

```
 * Restarting nginx
 * Stopping nginx nginx
   ...done.
 * Starting nginx nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
   ...done.
   ...done.
```

If I run

```
lsof -i :80 or sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

I get nothing.  Nothing on port 80

Then I run the below:

```
sudo netstat -pan | grep ":80"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8070          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15056/uwsgi     
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39567      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39564      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39584      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39566      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39571      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39580      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39562      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39582      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39586      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39575      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39579      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39560      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39587      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39591      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.170.35.97:39589      10.158.58.13:8080       TIME_WAIT   -
```

I am stumped. How do I debug this?

I am using uwsgi with a proxy pass on port 8070.  uwsgi is running.  Nginx is not.  I am using ubuntu 12.4

Below are the relevant portions of my nginx conf file

```
upstream uwsgi_frontend {
          server 127.0.0.1:8070;
        }
server {
listen 80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        location = /favicon.ico {
                  log_not_found off;
                }



                location / {
                       include uwsgi_params;
                       uwsgi_buffering off;

                       uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8070;
                 }
        }
```

Here is how I install nginx on ubuntu 12.04

```
nginx=stable;add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/$nginx;
apt-get update
apt get install nginx-full
```

Comment: I found the issue that I never had before.  I had to delete /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.  Then it worked.  My conf was in /etc/nginx/default

Comment: I was running Nginx+Varnish and had this error. The solution was top stop both, then start nginx first and then varnish.

Comment: you may try stopping named service.

Comment: had you removed your default from sites-enabled?

Comment: i tried all the solutions here. Checked all the ports in use (it was being used by NGINX itself) so i killed the port and restarted it. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

`[::]:80` is a ipv6 address.

This error can be caused if you have a nginx configuration that is listening on port 80 and also on port `[::]:80`.

I had the following in my default sites-available file:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

You can fix this by adding `ipv6only=on` to the `[::]:80` like this:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
```

For more information, see:

http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=8580

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen

Comment: You can also fix it by just removing the listen 80; because listen [::]:80 listents to both IPv4 and IPv6. Watch out though because some systems (like FreeBSD) separate the IPv4 and IPv6 sockets and then it won't work, but for Linux it should be fine. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen

Comment: Thanks for digging into this and providing an explanation to why deleting `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` helps with the above error.

Comment: Even when I comment out the ipv6 line, I still get the same error when I try `sudo service nginx restart`.  When I do `netstat -tulpn |grep 80`, I get only once nginx process (0.0.0.0:80).  Any ideas why it won't restart?

Comment: I second what @rednaw said, but instead of removing the listen, you can simply comment it out

Comment: Setting `ipv6only=on` fixed the problem, but nginx should really detect that it's trying to bind to the same interface:port twice.

Comment: @Nathan it is already added  in site-enabled's default file. but getting same error. help me

Comment: @Ashiya it's possible to get this error for a variety of reasons. Perhaps you have something else running on that port, like Apache (see other answer below)  Or maybe you have additional nginx config files that are binding to the port.

Comment: **ipv6only=on** is already in sites-available by default.  No need to add it.

Comment: This link helped me understand this answer in more detail: https://chrisjean.com/fix-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use/

Comment: I was forced to remove the `listen [::]:80` and leave only the `listen 80;` then it worked

Comment: _removing_ every occurrence of the `ipv6only` option (whether `on` or `off`) in every config file fixed the problem for me. `listen 80` and `listen [::]:80` now coexist peacefully in my config.

Answer (score 470):

I fixed this by running:

```bash
sudo apachectl stop
```

It turns out apache was running in the background and prevented nginx from starting on the desired port.

On Ubuntu, run:

```bash
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Comment: Use `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` to stop apache on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The reason is because you cannot have two web servers listening to the same port. Choose one, and if required, proxy. E.g. use nginx, but for certain requests (such as for `php` files), proxy to Apache port.

Comment: Same here on a fresh debian 9 install.

Comment: Thanks. But any idea why did it suddenly start? I didn't touch the server for a week, but it had started last night.

Comment: maybe your server rebooted and you have apache configured to start on boot? and or another service requires apache as a dependency. it might also help to know more about your OS setup

Comment: Thank for your solution. It works for me, I use Google Cloud Platform

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you! 
I used `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @lfender6445 Thanks so much. Would definitely not have found this on my own. Upvote!

Comment: I made a Debian full-upgrade, after the reboot suddenly apache ran which it never did before...

Comment: generally you can check out which process is listening port 80 alrady by `sudo netstat -lntup | grep :80`.

Comment: Every now and then, with every update, Ubuntu reinstalls apache for some reason. This was the culprit for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 391):

My case is different, I had to kill the running Nginx process to restart it.

Instead of

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

I had to use:

```
sudo pkill -f nginx & wait $!
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

Comment: best to stick to operating on your nginx service in one way. I had it get to a bad state by using `nginx -s reload` instead of using `systemctl`

Comment: Worked for me after restarting an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment broke my application.

Comment: sudo pkill -f nginx & wait $! this line saved my day, thanks.

Answer (score 51):

try to do this command

```
sudo fuser -k 443/tcp
service nginx restart
```

the *fuser* command will find the process id(PID) and the *-k* flag will kill the process enabling the nginx restart.

Comment: This worked perfectly :)

Comment: Wish this had more upvotes, took me forever to figure this out

Comment: I would love some explanation as to why this only needed to be run once and everything still worked after reboot.

Answer (score 50):

I found the issue that I never had before.

I just had to delete `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. Then it worked.

This deletion will delete the symlink only, As backup you can find default file in
`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

My conf was in `/etc/nginx/default`.

Comment: +1 This solution worked for me, but then I thought there must be something in default that is actually causing the problem, so I dug a bit deeper and provided an answer with more info.

Comment: I would argue that deleting the default site configuration template is not the best solution - commenting the line that contains `listen 80;` in that same template already solves the problem and correctly so. Your trick works but it's not what I would future readers of your question to do. That's why I suggest you select @Nathan's answer as the correct answer.

Comment: I had the same problem after running `apt-get dist-upgrade`, which upgraded the nginx package, which created a link in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. nginx was trying to load this default config, which listens to port 80 over IPv6, then it was also loading my read my real configs. Removing that symlink fixed the problem.

Comment: ***YOU DON'T NEED TO DELETE*** `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, simply remove the symbolic link to it - `sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: I experienced this issue when trying to run `nginx` on port 8080 and `varnish` on port 80 and similar to this answer, I found the problem to an `nginx` default config still listening on port 80 even though my `sites-available` configs all listened on port 8080. This was located at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default`

Answer (score 31):

I was also getting the same error.

> nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

and when i typed the localhost in the browser, then i was getting

> It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
instead of nginx welcome page, apache2 is running on the same port,

1. find the apache2 **ports.conf** file

   ```
   sudo /etc/apache2/ports.conf
   ```
2. change the port other then `80` , i make it as `70`
3. save the file
4. restart your system

it will works for you also, if you type the localhost in the browser, you will get nginx welcome page

Comment: You may simply not want to run both Apache2 and nginx at the same time. I found the Apache installation starts the service. So, I issued "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop", and then was able to start nginx normally. This also saves you from rebooting your system.

Comment: You are right that deleting the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default sym link does prevent it from listening on two ports. I find it actually a bit annoying that every tutorial on nginx starts by suggesting everyone delete the "default" link but that is a different topic I suppose.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky switch Apache to a different port?

Answer (score 20):

My issue was that I had overlapping listen directives. I have managed to figure out overlapping directives by running

```
grep -r listen /etc/nginx/*
```

Two files were listening at the same port:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:           listen 80;  
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf:    listen 80;
```

Comment: That's a very neat way to check things: `grep -r listen /etc/nginx/*` thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thank you sir! One question though, won't modifying the other listening to port 80 to let's say 70 cause any errors?

Comment: I have multiple domains. So, it seems this was only a problem because they were listening for the same host.

Answer (score 15):

I solved by running

```
sudo killall apache2

sudo fuser -k 443/tcp
```

finally

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem in letsencrypt (certbot) and nginx,

ref: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5486

this error does not have a solution yet

so, a changed a cron for renew <s>(putting a reload after renew)</s> (using suggest from certbot)

```
-- in /etc/cron.d/certbot
from
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew 
to
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

logs (short):

```
-- in /var/log/syslog
Jun 10 00:14:25 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Certbot...
Jun 10 00:14:38 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid$
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: Hook command "nginx" returned error c$
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: Error output from nginx:
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 $
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f$
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 $
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f$
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 $
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f$
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 $
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f$
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 $
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f$
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost certbot[22222]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Jun 10 00:14:41 localhost systemd[1]: Started Certbot.


-- in /var/log/nginx/error.log
2018/06/10 00:14:27 [notice] 22233#22233: signal process started
2018/06/10 00:14:31 [notice] 22237#22237: signal process started
2018/06/10 00:14:33 [notice] 22240#22240: signal process started
2018/06/10 00:14:34 [notice] 22245#22245: signal process started
2018/06/10 00:14:38 [notice] 22255#22255: signal process started
2018/06/10 00:14:38 [error] 22255#22255: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No $
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Addr$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Addre$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Addr$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Addre$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Addr$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Addre$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Addr$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Addre$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Addr$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Addre$
2018/06/10 00:14:39 [emerg] 22261#22261: still could not bind()
```

Comment: super random, but this was what my issue was i believe. thanks for posting this. my error seemed to manifest because of a outdated domain entry it was trying to renew but couldn't because i didn't control the domain anymore.

Comment: I guess this is probably my issue too. but I need to wait to have a look

Answer (score 9):

Multiple services can be listening on the same port.
This issue typically comes from mixing Apache and NGINX on the same machine.

**To check:**

`sudo netstat -plant | grep 80`

**Stop Apache & Restart NGINX:**

`sudo systemctl stop apache2 && sudo systemctl restart nginx && sudo systemctl status nginx`

Answer (score 6):

I use supervisor to run Nginx and Gunicorn side by side on a Docker container.

This was the configuration used for supervisor :

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:gunicorn]
command = /project/start.sh
user = www-data

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx
```

The problem was how I launched Ngnix by default it runs in the foreground. This makes **supervisor retry** to run another instance of Nginx.

You can fix issue by adding `-g 'daemon off;'` to the command line or `daemon off;` on top of the config file, Nginx stayed in the foreground, supervisor stopped trying to run another instance.

Answer (score 4):

Open `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with editor and **comment out** this line-

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Restart nginx and you are good to go!

Answer (score 4):

**In my case, I have checked the processes in linux `ps -aux | grep www-data` for www-data user and see apache is runing due to this my nginx can't start and show the following error but `I have fixed the issue by stopping apache2 and after it start the nginx`**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First change apache listen port 80 to 8080
apache in /etc/apache2/ports.conf include

```
Listen 1.2.3.4:80 to 1.2.3.4:8080
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service httpd restart    // in case of centos
```

then add nginx as reverse proxy server that will listen apache port

```
server {
 listen   1.2.3.4:80;
 server_name  some.com;

 access_log  /var/log/nginx/something-access.log;

 location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }


location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|js|jpeg|png)$ {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
}

location /404.html {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/40x.html;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
}

# put code for static content like js/css/images/fonts
}
```

After changes restart nginx server

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Now all traffic will be handled by nginx server and send all dynamic request to apache and static conten is served by nginx server.

For advance configuration like cache :

https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/slightly-more-advanced-configurations-for-nginx/#basic-nginx-caching

Answer (score 2):

With Nginx bind errors that happen while running [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/), disabling the perl module worked for me when every other solution failed.

```bash
sudo rm /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-perl.conf
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo killall -9 nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

Credit to [_az](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/nginx-server-fails-after-certbot-renew/142660/15).

To test:

```bash
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

Answer (score 1):

I met similar problem. the log is like below

```
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/10/31 12:54:20 [emerg] 128005#128005: still could not bind()
2018/10/31 12:54:23 [alert] 127997#127997: unlink() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2018/10/31 22:40:48 [info] 36948#36948: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:68
2018/10/31 22:50:40 [emerg] 37638#37638: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:18
2018/10/31 22:51:33 [info] 37787#37787: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:68
```

The last `[emerg]` shows that `duplicate listen options for [::]:80` which means that there are more than one nginx block file containing `[::]:80`.

My solution is to remove one of the `[::]:80` setting

P.S. you probably have default block file. My advice is to keep this file as default server for port 80. and remove `[::]:80` from other block files

Comment: i did it to, i am removed from other config file [::]:80 and its work! BUT ITS SECURE ? when no default listener ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, one of the services either Apache, Apache2 or Nginx was already running and due to that I was not able to start the other service.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the culprit turned out to be a server-block that contained:

```
        listen  127.0.0.1:80;
        listen  [::1]:80 ipv6only=on;
        server_name  localhost;
```

On Linux, a socket listening on a specific IP (e.g. `[::1]:80`) conflicts with a socket listening on the same port but any IP (i.e. `[::]:80`). Normally nginx will transparently deal with this problem by using a single socket behind this scenes. However, explicitly specifying `ipv6only` (or certain other options) on the listen directive forces nginx to (try to) create a separate socket for it, thus resulting in the `Address already in use` error.

Since `ipv6only=on` is the default anyway (since 1.3.4) the fix was simply to remove that option from this directive, and making sure `ipv6only` wasn't used anywhere else in my config.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on AWS Lightsail, used the top answer above

from

```
listen [::]:80;
```

to

```
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
```

and then click on "reboot" button inside my AWS account, I have main server Apache and Nginx as proxy.

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM - I had this issue. Basically, what I did is I started nginx with the normal `nginx` command and then tried to restart nginx with service `service nginx reload / restart` and then I get this error

SOLUTION - Just stopped nginx by using `nginx -s stop` and then restarted nginx server using `service nginx restart` issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I have added below code for my backend server that was causing issue. I added this on my `default` config of nginx.

Removing below code worked :)

```
    location  {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;       //remove
           proxy_http_version 1.1;                  //remove
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  //remove
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';   //remove
           proxy_set_header Host $host;             //remove
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;        //remove
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've reviewed several answers, each addressing different culprits for the same symptoms. Here may be some of the deeper causes:

## Conflicting configs in `/etc/nginx/`

**Problem: listening for the same host on the same port**

Without conflict, I have multiple nginx configs listening on the same port, ***but for different hosts*** via `server_name`:

- `0.0.0.0:80`
- `[::]:80`
- `0.0.0.0:443`
- `[::]:443`

[The answer about multiple configs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54222734/10343144) within `/etc/nginx/` only had a problem to begin with because each config listed the same host for the nginx `server_name` setting.

## Apache-Nginx

*Reverse proxy is okay; same host-port is not.*

Many discuss Apache conflicts, [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16806240/10343144), but I successfully have an Nginx-Apache reverse proxy server that clips along valiantly.

In reverse-proxy, Apache doesn't listen on the public port for the host; it listens on an internal port albeit for the same host. That's no conflict.

Nginx, Apache, and combination thereof isn't the cause *in this issue*. The issue is ***more than one config listening for the same host/domain on the same port***, regardless of combined web services.

## Letsencrypt, et cetera: use `fuser -k 443/tcp`

My solution was the [fuser -k 443/tcp answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548253/10343144), and everything continued working after reboot.

Remember, Letsencrypt heavily engages with whatever webserver it is told to. For me, it was Nginx, where my port errors were.

My likely culprit was attempting to get Letsencrypt certs while DNS wasn't quite ready, and it caused a log jam of port activity. ***Any other activity using web ports could do the same.***

My solution was to use `fuser -k 443/tcp` after restarting for `certbot` in the future.

---

*Concerning Letsencrypt-related causes, I wouldn't be surprised to find that the `--nginx` module for `certbot` gets an update that prevents this in the future.*

Answer (score 0):

I had several *.save files (emergency dumps from nano) from different NGINX config files in my sites-avilable dir. Once I deleted these .save files, NGINX restarted fine. I assumed these were harmless since there were no corresponding symlinks, but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To follow on to @lfender6445 and @SAURABH answers --

My problem was also the fact that after upgrading to Vagrant 2.2.2 Apache2 was running as a web server when the guest booted.    In the past I only had nginx as a web server.

vagrant ssh into the box and run the following command to disable Apache2 from starting up whenever the guest box boots:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

Exit ssh, vagrant halt, vagrant up.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I see that port 80 listened by Nginx:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9730/nginx
```

But when I try to restart it, I have the error:

```
    service nginx restart
Stopping nginx:                                            [FAILED]
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

My issue was in the config file, I am set PID file, and seems system cant catch it properly:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

When I removed it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by killing the running tailscaled instance (I did tailscale down beforehand, didn't work, kill the daemon instead.)

`sudo pkill -f tailscaled & wait $!`

Answer (score 0):

For those who have tried every suggested answer from here and other posts with no success, make sure that an unremover docker container is not using `port 80`

In my case I first used Nginx inside docker (compose) with `network_mode:host` on default port 80. This makes Nginx container run just like Nginx on host (on port 80).

Then I installed Nginx on host server, but I could not run start it. It failed with `[::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)` error since Docker Nginx container was bound to host's port 80.

If this is the case for you have 3 options:

1. (if you want Nginx installed both on the host and inside docker) Stop Docker Nginx container. Then run Docker Nginx container without `network_mode:host` and install Nginx on the host. This way you can have multiple Nginx containers running inside docker without interferring host's Nginx.
2. (if you want Nginx installed on the host) Simply stop Docker Nginx container and run Nginx on the host
3. (if you want Nginx installed inside docker) Remove Nginx on the host and run Nginx inside Docker with `network_mode:host`. In this case you have to manage Nginx settings from Docker