# Change Nginx port from 80

Tags: nginx

Im trying to change the port that `Nginx` uses from port `80` to `5555`

I've gone into `nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` 
and edited:

```
server {
         listen 5555;
}
```

But when I try to restart I get:

```
$ service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx.
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Another service is the port.
Use `sudo netstat -plnt` to see which service is using the port and stop it, or configure it otherwise.

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972792/nginx-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use) and [this](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/troubleshooting/emerg-bind-failed-98-address-already-in-use/).