# 500 internal server error Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am having some trouble with Nginx i m getting [b]500 internal server error[/b]

So i went check the logs at[i] /var/log/nginx/error.log[/i]

And i found these Error :

```
2015/01/11 21:16:00 [emerg] 3365#0: bind() to xx.xxx.xxx.x:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/01/11 21:16:00 [emerg] 3365#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/01/11 21:16:00 [emerg] 3365#0: still could not bind()
```

I readed in another threat that it s because some other service is runing in same pot so i used this command : netstat -tulpn | grep --color :80

```
tcp        0      0 xx.xxx.xxx.x:80             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3102/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3363/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      3102/nginx
tcp        0      0 :::8081                     :::*                        LISTEN      3363/httpd
```

So for me that mean that Nginx is runing well in the right port !

Please help

Answer (score 1):

take a look at it: 
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/troubleshooting/emerg-bind-failed-98-address-already-in-use/

"Then it means nginx or some other process is already using port 80.
You can kill it using:
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
And then try restarting nginx again:
service nginx start"

and this one:
[nginx - nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972792/nginx-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use)

Comment: sudo  service nginx restart