# ngix 2 server block in one linux server

Tags: linux, nginx

I can't restart nginx because I got `[emerg] 6594#6594: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)`. How does multiple server block work? Without the staging server block my config is working fine.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;

    server_name staging-api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says that Address already in use. Which mean there is a process which is already using that port 443. Find the process which is using that port kill it and try starting nginx again!

Comment: @MukeshVerma what is port 443 actually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx will not start (Address already in use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303401/nginx-will-not-start-address-already-in-use)

Comment: 443 Port is a reserved port which is used for https connections just like 80 is used by normal http connection!!

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -anp | grep :443` chgeck which app take over the port 443,and if not necessary, kill it and then restart nginx