# Reason behind this problem=>nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: nginx, server

I have a problem with nginx.I know the solution of this.
it all in here [Nginx will not start (Address already in use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303401/nginx-will-not-start-address-already-in-use/42303738) . But I don't realized why this happened?
Can Anyone describe me why this happen?? is it for default apache??my apache is already stop..i want to know the reason

Comment: run `netstat -nlp` and see which process listen on the port

Comment: PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36475           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::36475                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      -

Comment: you can see that some process listens on port 80, I don't see it in your output but you can find the PID, and then run `ps aux | grep $pid` and see some more info regarding the process. Basically you can kill it, but maybe you need to investigate more about why and how it started in the first place