# Nodejs not running in server

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, centos, centos-6.9

I am trying to launch nodejs in my server. this is my node.js code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, 'xx.xx.xx.xx');
console.log('Server running at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/');
```

this is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server{
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
#
```

I also deleted a few lines from `default.conf` because it was showing up error `nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)` and following @[rednaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972792/nginx-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use/16798023#comment21754128_15101745)

I am trying to run node.js in my `xx.xx.xx.xx` server. Now it's just showing [this](https://prnt.sc/jaqlfe) at http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ and `This site can’t be reached xx.xx.xx.xx refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the port number **i.e not in use** to listen.

Do it some thing like this----

```
var http =  require("http");
function onRequest(request, response) {
console.log("Request received.");
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8083);
```

In my scenario the port number **8080** was already in use....So i used

another port number like **8083**....It works...

Comment: should i put 8083 in nginx.conf file too?

Comment: yes you have to change where you port no is specified.

Comment: it didn't work. the same code above is perfectly working in my pc - centos7. not working in my server centos6.9