# How to test a server with a request without the “Host” header field

Tags: nginx, curl, nginx-config, server-name

I have a server that is using [Nginx's 444 to drop connections to undefined hosts](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names):

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name "";
    return      444; 
}
```

But I can't figure out how to test if it's working.

Here are a few things I've tried, stabbing in the dark:

```
$ curl -I mysite.com --header 'Host: ""'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

$ curl -I mysite.com --header ''
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

I'm trying to get that 444!

Here's the relevant portion of my nginx **mysite.conf** file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "";
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

So either I'm testing it wrong, or I'm testing it correctly but the missing host header is still getting captured by my second server block and redirecting.

Comment: To check the how your server process requests without HTTP `Host` header you should accrss it by its IP address )) And you trying to config your server incorrect way, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362642/nginx-doesnt-listen-on-port-80-twice/60362700#60362700) is working example.

Comment: Giving you an example: assuming your server has IP address `1.2.3.4` and the domain name it is serving is `example.com`, commands `curl -I example.com` and `curl -I 1.2.3.4 --header 'Host: example.com` are equivalent.

Comment: You could try: `curl --http1.0` - but I would be surprised if `server_name "";` matches requests without a `Host` header - I would expect Nginx to use the `default_server` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works with curl 7.47:

`curl -I --header Host: mysite.com`

Note that the argument to the header option is just `Host:` (`'Host: '` and `'Host: ""'` won't work)

Latest versions of curl may have a `--http0.9` option that may get you the same result, but I didn't test it.