# NGINX - All requests going through single server name domain CNAMES incude hyphen

Tags: nginx, cname

I have the following CNAMES xyz.abc.com, xyz-1.abc.com and xyz-2.abc.com. server body looks like this

```
server
{
    listen 80 default_server deferred;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name xyz.abc.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
    }
}
```

All requests are going through and being redirected even though the server name is not in there.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I see the question details, but don't see the question itself, could you declare it explicitly?

Comment: Nginx will use the default server if a matching `server_name` is not found. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362642/nginx-doesnt-listen-on-port-80-twice/60362700#60362700) example.