# Redirect from http to https, nginx

Tags: azure, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, sidecar

I am using this configuration down for nginx, i am using it for sidecar in azure, following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl)
I can't figure it out what to change in the configuration to automatically redirect from `http://domain` to `https://domain`

```
# nginx Configuration File
# https://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
# Run as a less privileged user for security reasons.
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
http {
    #Redirect to https, using 307 instead of 301 to preserve post data
    server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        # Protect against the BEAST attack by not using SSLv3 at all. If you need to support older browsers (IE6) you may need to add
        # SSLv3 to the list of protocols below.
        ssl_protocols              TLSv1.2;
        # Ciphers set to best allow protection from Beast, while providing forwarding secrecy, as defined by Mozilla - https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Nginx
        ssl_ciphers                ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        # Optimize TLS/SSL by caching session parameters for 10 minutes. This cuts down on the number of expensive TLS/SSL handshakes.
        # The handshake is the most CPU-intensive operation, and by default it is re-negotiated on every new/parallel connection.
        # By enabling a cache (of type "shared between all Nginx workers"), we tell the client to re-use the already negotiated state.
        # Further optimization can be achieved by raising keepalive_timeout, but that shouldn't be done unless you serve primarily HTTPS.
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m; # a 1mb cache can hold about 4000 sessions, so we can hold 40000 sessions
        ssl_session_timeout  24h;
        # Use a higher keepalive timeout to reduce the need for repeated handshakes
        keepalive_timeout 300; # up from 75 secs default
        # remember the certificate for a year and automatically connect to HTTPS
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';
        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl.key;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:80; # TODO: replace port if app listens on port other than 80
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
After the suggestion in the first answer it didn't worked, with the two blocks added it was like this:

```
# nginx Configuration File
# https://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
# Run as a less privileged user for security reasons.
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
http {
    #Redirect to https, using 307 instead of 301 to preserve post data
   server {
        # catch HTTP requests for all valid HTTP `Host` header values
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name _; # list all your domain names here
        # do redirection to HTTPS
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        # default server listening on port 80
        # getting here means the HTTP `Host` header is missing or had an incorrect value
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        # close the connection immediately
        return 444;
    }
    server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        # Protect against the BEAST attack by not using SSLv3 at all. If you need to support older browsers (IE6) you may need to add
        # SSLv3 to the list of protocols below.
        ssl_protocols              TLSv1.2;
        # Ciphers set to best allow protection from Beast, while providing forwarding secrecy, as defined by Mozilla - https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Nginx
        ssl_ciphers                ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        # Optimize TLS/SSL by caching session parameters for 10 minutes. This cuts down on the number of expensive TLS/SSL handshakes.
        # The handshake is the most CPU-intensive operation, and by default it is re-negotiated on every new/parallel connection.
        # By enabling a cache (of type "shared between all Nginx workers"), we tell the client to re-use the already negotiated state.
        # Further optimization can be achieved by raising keepalive_timeout, but that shouldn't be done unless you serve primarily HTTPS.
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m; # a 1mb cache can hold about 4000 sessions, so we can hold 40000 sessions
        ssl_session_timeout  24h;
        # Use a higher keepalive timeout to reduce the need for repeated handshakes
        keepalive_timeout 300; # up from 75 secs default
        # remember the certificate for a year and automatically connect to HTTPS
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';
        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl.key;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:80; # TODO: replace port if app listens on port other than 80
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use two additional server blocks:

```
server {
    # catch HTTP requests for all valid HTTP `Host` header values
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain www.domain; # list all your domain names here
    # do redirection to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
server {
    # default server listening on port 80
    # getting here means the HTTP `Host` header is missing or had an incorrect value
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    # close the connection immediately
    return 444;
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362642/nginx-doesnt-listen-on-port-80-twice/60362700#60362700) answer for additional details on this configuration.

**Update**

Checking the documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl) given by OP looks like the provided example uses nginx container listening on port 443 taking the TLS encryption job and proxying requests to some "Hello World" example container that listen on port 80. To do the HTTP to HTTPS redirection via the nginx container you can try to change the "Hello World" example container listening port to 8080 and made nginx proxying the incoming requests to that port instead of port 80. Try the following configuration:

**`nginx.conf`**

```
# nginx Configuration File
# https://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
# Run as a less privileged user for security reasons.
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
http {
    #Redirect to https, using 307 instead of 301 to preserve post data
   server {
        # catch HTTP requests for all valid HTTP `Host` header values
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name _; # list all your domain names here
        # do redirection to HTTPS
        return 307 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        # default server listening on port 80
        # getting here means the HTTP `Host` header is missing or had an incorrect value
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        # close the connection immediately
        return 444;
    }
    server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        # Protect against the BEAST attack by not using SSLv3 at all. If you need to support older browsers (IE6) you may need to add
        # SSLv3 to the list of protocols below.
        ssl_protocols              TLSv1.2;
        # Ciphers set to best allow protection from Beast, while providing forwarding secrecy, as defined by Mozilla - https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Nginx
        ssl_ciphers                ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        # Optimize TLS/SSL by caching session parameters for 10 minutes. This cuts down on the number of expensive TLS/SSL handshakes.
        # The handshake is the most CPU-intensive operation, and by default it is re-negotiated on every new/parallel connection.
        # By enabling a cache (of type "shared between all Nginx workers"), we tell the client to re-use the already negotiated state.
        # Further optimization can be achieved by raising keepalive_timeout, but that shouldn't be done unless you serve primarily HTTPS.
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m; # a 1mb cache can hold about 4000 sessions, so we can hold 40000 sessions
        ssl_session_timeout  24h;
        # Use a higher keepalive timeout to reduce the need for repeated handshakes
        keepalive_timeout 300; # up from 75 secs default
        # remember the certificate for a year and automatically connect to HTTPS
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';
        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl.key;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

**`deploy-aci.yaml`**

```
api-version: 2019-12-01
location: westus
name: app-with-ssl
properties:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-with-ssl
    properties:
      image: nginx
      ports:
      - port: 80
        protocol: TCP
      - port: 443
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      volumeMounts:
      - name: nginx-config
        mountPath: /etc/nginx
  - name: my-app
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld
      ports:
      - port: 8080
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
  volumes:
  - secret:
      ssl.crt: <Enter contents of base64-ssl.crt here>
      ssl.key: <Enter contents of base64-ssl.key here>
      nginx.conf: <Enter contents of base64-nginx.conf here>
    name: nginx-config
  ipAddress:
    ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
    type: Public
  osType: Linux
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Comment: it didn't worked, do i need to take those two blocks out of the `http { } ` block? I edit the question so you can see

Comment: No, they should be within the `http` context. This is something azure-related. I'm not familiar with azure, but following your link I see the example where two different containers used, nginx one listening on port 443 and something named `mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld` listening on port 80. To make the above configuration workable your nginx container should listen both 80 and 443 ports.

Comment: @ШурбескиХристијан Check the update to the answer (it is only a guess, but I think it has a big chances to work). **Update** No, most likely to make it workable you should made the `mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld` container listening on port 8080 instead of 80.

Comment: @ШурбескиХристијан According to [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/34082284-support-for-port-mapping) information non-symmetric port mapping doesn't supported by Azure (and not planned at all), so the [`ACI Hello World`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azuredocs-aci-helloworld) container isn't an appropriate choice to check HTTP to HTTPS redirection. However its [`index.js`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aci-helloworld/blob/master/app/index.js) file contains a `var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80, ...` line (to be continued)

Comment: @ШурбескиХристијан which means you can change listening port via the `PORT` environment variable, but I don't know how it can be done with Azure containers.