# Nginx: Redirecting server names in one paragraph

Tags: nginx

I using the Nginx configuration below and it works fine.

However, I'm using three paragraphs `{...}` for redirections, can this be optimized to a single paragraph or set directly in the main paragraph ?

```
upstream mywebsite_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3003;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {

    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_pass http://mywebsite_upstream;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com;
}
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com;
}
```

Comment: If this server only hosts the single domain, you can use the `default_server` to redirect any other hostname to it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968).

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your comment. The server does host other domains as well.

Comment: @DevonDahon Since your server hosts other domains, I'll recommend to have an additional default server block like shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362700/7121513) answer example. Since your are using HTTPS as well you'll need the second default `server` block listening on port 443. For SSL settings of that block you can use any self-signed key/cert (don't use you domain key/cert for that).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure you can:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  mywebsite.com;
    # SSL config here
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
```

I think you'll need to copy all SSL-related configuration from your main server block to the second one.

I think (and I'm not [alone](https://serverfault.com/questions/896543/nginx-certbot-certificate-www-and-non-www/896555#896555), check an answer under the link) that nginx config produced by `certbot` is a crap and it is better to do nginx config changes manually a leave for `certbot` only a certificate receiving/renewing:

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www -d hostname -d hostname ...
```

**Update**

When your server hosts other domains (and even if ins't) it is a good practice to have an additional `server` block serving requests than does not contain a valid domain name (or does not have `Host` HTTP header at all - those are typically port scanners, vulnerability searchers etc.) To close suspicious connections on port 443 you'll need minimal SSL config within that block. It's best to use a self-signed key and certificate for that purpose. For generating a pair of self-signed key/cart in one line you can use the following command:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -subj "/CN=localhost" -keyout /etc/nginx/server.key -out /etc/nginx/server.crt
```

You can use special nginx 444 code (close connection without any response) for the suspicious connections:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;

    return 444;
}
```

To simplify `certbot` key renewing process with the command like given above, you can add an additional section to all your server blocks for hosted domains (including that ones used for redirection too):

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www;
}
```