# Nginx 2 different domains on one server

Tags: web-services, nginx, ssl, single-sign-on, keycloak

I'd like to know how to configure nginx to get 2 domains working on one server (1 ip address).
I want to setup a Keycloak SSO next to a bookstack instance.

My issue is that when I want to access bookstack.domain.com it redirects to keycloak.domain.com.

**Here's my /etc/nginx/conf.d/keycloak.conf :**

```
upstream keycloak {
# Use IP Hash for session persistence
ip_hash;

# List of Keycloak servers
server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}


server {
listen 80;
server_name keycloak.domain.com;

# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS
location / { 
return 301 https://\$server_name\$request_uri;
}
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name keycloak.domain.com;

ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate_key.key;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_pass http://keycloak;
}
}
```

**Here's my /etc/nginx/conf.d/bookstack.conf :**

```
server {
    listen 3480;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/bookstack_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/bookstack_error.log;
    server_name bookstack.domain.com;
    root        /var/www/bookstack/public;
    #
    # redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
    #
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
  listen 5443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate_key.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AE;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

  server_name bookstack.domain.com;

  #HSTS
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

  root /var/www/bookstack/public;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/bookstack_access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/bookstack_error.log;

  client_max_body_size 1G;
  fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

  index  index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ ^/(?:\.htaccess|data|config|db_structure\.xml|README) {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
    expires 30d;
    access_log off;
  }
}
```

Please let me know :)

Comment: does this work `https://bookstack.domain.com:5443` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly expected nginx behavior for the given configuration. One of the `server` blocks always act as **default server** for any request arriving on some IP/port combination no matter what is the `Host` HTTP header value. Here is an official [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) on this subject. You can use `default_server` parameter for the `listen` directive to explicitly specify `server` block that should act as the default server or it will be the first `server` block that listen on those IP/port otherwise. On multihomed servers things can be more complicated, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362700/7121513).

Now back to the question. You have four server blocks in your configuration: first one listen on TCP port 80 (default port for `http://` scheme), second one listen on TCP port 443 (default port for `https://` scheme), one listen on port 3480 and the last one listen on port 5443. Since there is only one `server` block listening each port, each `server` block will act as default server for any request coming to that port. So if you type `http://bookstack.domain.com` in your browser address bar, default port 80 for `http://` scheme will be used and your request will be redirected to `https://keycloak.domain.com`. You are using

```
return 301 https://\$server_name\$request_uri;
```

for redirection, and the `$server_name` variable will be always `keycloak.domain.com` for that server block (read [this](https://serverfault.com/a/706439/498657) answer to understand the difference between `$host`, `$http_host` and `$server_name` variables). If you explicitly specify the port and type `http://bookstack.domain.com:3480`, your request will be served by the third `server` block thus being redirected to `https://bookstack.domain.com` (here your are using `$host` variable which is right). Default TCP port `https://` scheme is 443. But the only `server` block that listen on that port is for `keycloak.domain.com`! Oops. The only way you can reach your `bookstack.domain.com` is to type `https://bookstack.domain.com:5443` in your browser. And if you correctly understand all the above information, you can type `https://keycloak.domain.com:5443` too, it won't made any difference.

Well, I tried to explain what happened here with your nginx configuration. Get rid of non-standard ports as @Evil_skunk recommends you in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69319584/7121513). Don't forget to clear your browser cache before trying new configuration - permanent HTTP 301 redirects are often cached by the browsers, unlike temporary HTTP 302 redirects.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer. I did try to specify the ports as you said and it was working for bookstack but not for keycloak.  I got rid of non-standard ports as you and @Evil_skunk said and now everything is working great ! My problem was that I thought I couldn't be listening on the same ports for 2 different servers.

Comment: Server block that should process a request is selected by nginx according to the [`Host` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) value. If it isn't match any of the server names specified by the `server_name` directive (or if there is no `Host` header at all), request will be processed by the default server block. You can have any number of server blocks, but their server names should not match each other.

Answer (score 1):

Your keycloak config seems ok

It listen on port `80 (http)` and port `443 (https)` and all requests to `80 (http)` are redirected to `443 (https)`

Your bookstack config looks wrong for me
It does not listen to port `80` or `443` (instead it listen to `5443` and `3480`). If you don't have some kind of special port forwarding then I think request to `bookstack.domain.com` will never reach the nginx-server defined in `bookstack.conf` and as a result the only matching server will serve the request => keycloak

You should change `bookstack.conf`'s Listen ports:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   #... redirect to https
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   #ssl config, webroot, ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got rid of non-standard ports as you said and now my bookstack is working great ! I thought that I couldn't be listening on the same ports for 2 different servers.