# Nginx not targeting the good port for the api

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to Dockerize a classic NodeJS (Express, TS) + Angular application using nginx, but I struggle binding correctly my api throught nginx.

In fact, it seems that nginx target my localhost:80...

[image]

...while I want it to target my `localhost:3000`.
When I manually ping that url while adding `:3000` after `localhost`, it works.

I'm trying to keep my code simple. Here are my different files.

Back Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:15.14-alpine AS build

RUN mkdir -p /build/tmp
WORKDIR /build/tmp

COPY . .
RUN npm ci

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Front Dockerfile :

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:15.14-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/front /usr/share/nginx/html
```

dockercompose.yml :

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mymusicads-front:
    container_name: mymusicads-front
    build:
      context: ./front
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mymusicads-api
    networks:
      - front-back

  mymusicads-api:
    container_name: mymusicads-api
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - front-back

networks:
  front-back:
    driver: bridge
```

nginx.conf :

```
events{}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    upstream api {
      server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name front;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html;
      location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name api;

      location /api/ {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
          proxy_redirect off;
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks !

EDIT :
By checking the error, we can see we're obtaining my Angular index.html file as a response, instead of the JSON object my API should return, which may signify an proxying error. Seems like nginx is missing the `location /api/` instruction, or maybe the whole `server` one.

Comment: Don't you need to use container name `mymusicads-api` instead of `localhost` with the `proxy_pass`, e.g. `proxy_pass http://mymusicads-api:3000/`?

Comment: Hello Ivan ! It's not working either, but I still have the same error, which may mean my nginx config doesn't even detect I'm trying to proxy to my api. Any suggestion ?

Comment: From your screenshot I see that some HTML `<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n <head>\n...` is returned instead of JSON object. Look at that HTML body text, maybe it has some clue?

Comment: Indeed, it is my Angular index.html. What I think is that while reverse proxying, my nginx stop at the first server and consider every operation like a call to my angular app, which always return the index.html.
I've tried to swap the two server declarations, but it doesn't work too.
I'll precise this in the original question :)

Comment: OMG, I didn't notice you are using two server blocks. Of course only one will pick up your request. Wait a minute, I'll try to write an alternate config as an answer...

Comment: Check the update to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use multiple `server` blocks in your configuration, nginx chooses the server block to process your request by the HTTP [`Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) header value. If it won't match any of the specified server names (or if the `Host` header is absent at all), the **default** server block will be used. You can specify the default server block explicitly using `default_server` flag for the [`listen`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive. If you don't specify it explicitly, the very first server block listening on the specific port will be used. See the [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) official documentation page or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362700/7121513) answer for even more details.

Try this configuration instead:

```
events {}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://mymusicads-api:3000/;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to expose the node.js port 3000 to the outer world, it is only `mymusicads-front` container that should have an access to that port. According to [What is the difference between docker-compose ports vs expose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801772/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-compose-ports-vs-expose) SO thread your `dockercompose.yml` file should be something like

```yml
version: '3.4'

services:
  mymusicads-front:
    container_name: mymusicads-front
    build:
      context: ./front
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mymusicads-api
    networks:
      - front-back

  mymusicads-api:
    container_name: mymusicads-api
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 3000
    networks:
      - front-back

networks:
  front-back:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much for those explanations ! I'm having a 502 Bad Gateway now, which is definitely an improvement, I will update my question when I found how to solve that.
Answer accepted ✔

Comment: The corresponding line from the nginx error log can be really helpful to track that. Additionally, any request like `/api/addata/Lucho` will appear at your node.js container as a `/addata/Lucho`.If that behavior is undesirable, change `proxy_pass http://mymusicads-api/;` directive to `proxy_pass http://mymusicads-api;` (without the trailing slash). See [A little confused about trailing slash behavior in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx) SO thread for the details.

Comment: Is it supposed to hit `http://mymusicads-api/...` then ? It still targets `http://localhost/api/...`.

The error line is actually
`2021/10/26 14:08:15 [error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.176.1, server: , request: "GET /api/addata/Lucho HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.176.2:80/addata/Lucho", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/dashboard`

Comment: I'm sorry, of course it should include the port number: `proxy_pass http://mymusicads-api:3000/;` (or `proxy_pass http://mymusicads-api:3000;` if you need to preserve the `/api` prefix for the node.js application).

Comment: It works, tysm Ivan ! Port + removing the final slash was the solution, since I use `/api/...` on my backend to call this endpoint.