# Using multiple nginx config files in sites-available with proxy pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am wanting to use multiple files declared at

> /etc/nging/sites-available/

symlinked to:

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Now the files look similar to below - call this team1.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /team1/app3/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team1/app3/location/region(.*) /path3/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
  location /team1/app4/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team1/app4/location/region(.*) /path4/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
  location /team1/app5/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team1/app5/location/region(.*) /path5/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
}
```

Call this team2.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /team2/app3/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team2/app3/location/region(.*) /path3/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
  location /team2/app4/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team2/app4/location/region(.*) /path4/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
  location /team2/app5/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team2/app5/location/region(.*) /path5/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
}
```

I wanted to keep them separate - hence the separate files - however, with two files, nginx just seems to read the first one and 404 anything in the second one - so I suspect there is a conflict somewhere....

The files are pretty arbitrary - I just wanted to demonstrate - the paths etc, will vary between files..

Any help would be great - apologies if I've missed something obvious..

Cheers

Comment: This spans 2 servers at port 80 so I expect you have some error message about it

Comment: @user39950 There will be no errors, but since the `server_name` directive isn't specified for both, the first one will act as the default server processing any request and the second one will never be used at all.

Comment: thanks both - @IvanShatsky  I'm a bit of a novice with nginx so i appreciate the guidance - whats the best way to approach this then? as I expect numerous config files to be used... If I add a server name it works - but whats the best practice for this? as everything will be served off a single domain and proxied based on path

Comment: @JoshW Usual approach is to use a single file for each individual site (in apache terms it can be called vhost). You can use some common code that can be shared across different sites as a separate file and then include it wherever needed using the `include` directive, but don't place those files inside the `sites-enabled` directory - everything being placed in that directory is included under the `http` context, not the `server` one.

Comment: @IvanShatsky - makes sense - where should they reside then? `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` ? 

What about the clashing of ports comment and the `server_name` - I think I've tried serving them from this directory and had the same issue - but perhaps that was the `server_name` issue again...

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, so I'm writing this as an answer.

> where should they reside then?

Check your main `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` configuration. I think something like

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
```

is present there. Notice that those files are included under the `http` context. So you can use whatever you want, but not the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` or any file inside the `sites-enabled` directory. Something like `/etc/nginx/shared/...` will be ok, I think. I don't use those `sites-available`/`sites-enabled` directories at all in favor of `conf.d` directory - read the [Difference in sites-available vs sites-enabled vs conf.d directories (Nginx)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/527630/difference-in-sites-available-vs-sites-enabled-vs-conf-d-directories-nginx) discussion on ServerFault.

> What about the clashing of ports

You can have any number of `server` blocks listening the same port. Nginx will choose the right block according to the HTTP `Host` header value. If it isn't match any of the defined server names in any server block (or the `Host` header is missing at all from the request), the **default** server will be used to serve it. See the [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) official documentation page or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362700/7121513) answer for even more details.

Answer (score 1):

Thats great - this is all teaching me a lot! so thanks for that!

I have gone with the following structure:

within `/etc/nginx/conf.d/main.conf`:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name  service.com;
 access_log           /var/log/nginx/test-service-access.log;
 error_log            /var/log/nginx/test-service-error.log;
 include              /etc/nginx/shared/*.conf;
}
```

Then within `/etc/nginx/shared/`:

I have both files:

`team1.conf`:

```
  location /team1/app3/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team1/app3/location/region(.*) /path3/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
  location /team1/app4/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team1/app4/location/region(.*) /path4/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
  location /team1/app5/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team1/app5/location/region(.*) /path5/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
```

`team2.conf`:

```
  location /team2/app3/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team2/app3/location/region(.*) /path3/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
  location /team2/app4/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team2/app4/location/region(.*) /path4/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
  location /team2/app5/location/region {
  rewrite ^/team2/app5/location/region(.*) /path5/healthcheck$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://this.is.the.backend.app.example;
  }
```

This seems to work ok - hopefully this is an accepted way of structuring it. @IvanShatsky