# Nginx running four sites, one unresponsive [non webdev.]

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

A couple of years ago I set up four websites on a nginx server, recently I ran into SQL troubles and decided to rebuild *site 1* which ran the SQL backend. However, ever since I am running into a persistent 502 voor *site 1* which I can't seem to get a hold of.

Initially I was running into port issues but this does not seems to be fixed after running through; [nginx - nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972792/nginx-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use)

At this point I am stil stuck with a: `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 01.01.01.100, server: www.site1.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5001/", host: "site1.com"` in the nginx error.log.

Could someone give me a push in the right direction?:(

I don't have a webdev background, my focus is on scientific research through Python and I like to play around with HTML/CSS etc. Server management isn't my cup of tea I'm afraid :(.

Edit 1;

`netstat -ln4t` displays:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5003          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5004          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Am I correct in thinking this means :5001 is not up and running?

Edit 2:

Alright, next step. Nginx calls on four seperate Gunicorn sockets (@ `/etc/systemd/system`) , one for each site, which in turn calls on individual Django backends (*site 1* socket is comparable with *site 2* socket).

Running:

```
sudo systemctl status site1.gunicorn
```

Results in:

```
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-03-20 11:23:40 UTC; 
 *techbabble*
Main PID: 23301 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
*techbabble*
Mar 20 11:23:40 site1.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Gunicorn daemon
```

It seems I am onto something!

1. `sudo systemctl deamon-reload`
2. `sudo systemctl restart site1.gunicorn`
3. `sudo systemctl status site1.gunicorn`

Again, a step further, the socket (?) is up! Through the 502 is still persisting, turning off and on nginx didn't solve this.

Comment: Is `http://127.0.0.1:5001/` running?

Comment: selinux enabled? what does `netstat -ln4t` display?

Comment: It doesn't look like it is running. Its a bit difficult for us to help with this, without knowing how it is run. Do you know how to restart it? Otherwise you can perhaps search for service files or inactive services, check bash_history etc.

Comment: I understand this is a bit of a black box :(. Thanks for now, I will pick it up tomorrow.